# How to have 2 outputs from 2 different functions in one line?

Tags: python

So the program should take a number and then should print this number using text.

```
print("Enter your number")
Number = int(input())


def number_to_text_ones(ones):
    if ones == 1:
        print("one")
    elif ones == 2:
        print("two")
    elif ones == 3:
        print("three")
    elif ones == 4:
        print("four")
    elif ones == 5:
        print("five")
    elif ones == 6:
        print("six")
    elif ones == 7:
        print("seven")
    elif ones == 8:
        print("eight")
    elif ones == 9:
        print("nine")


def number_to_text_tens(tens):
    if tens == 2:
        print("twenty ")
    elif tens == 3:
        print("thirty ")
    elif tens == 4:
        print("fourry ")
    elif tens == 5:
        print("fifty ")
    elif tens == 6:
        print("sixty ")
    elif tens == 7:
        print("seventy ")
    elif tens == 8:
        print("eighty ")
    elif tens == 9:
        print("ninety ")


def number_to_text_hundreds(hundreds):

    if hundreds == 1:
        print("one hundred")
    elif hundreds == 2:
        print("two hundreds")
    elif hundreds == 3:
        print("three hundreds")
    elif hundreds == 4:
        print("four hundreds")
    elif hundreds == 5:
        print("five hundreds")
    elif hundreds == 6:
        print("six hundreds")
    elif hundreds == 7:
        print("seven hundreds")
    elif hundreds == 8:
        print("eight hundreds")
    elif hundreds == 9:
        print("nine hundreds")


if Number == 0:
    print("zero")
elif Number == 10:
    print("ten")
elif Number == 11:
    print("eleven")
elif Number == 12:
    print("twelve")
elif Number == 13:
    print("thirteen")
elif Number == 14:
    print("fourteen")
elif Number == 15:
    print("fifteen")
elif Number == 16:
    print("sixteen")
elif Number == 17:
    print("seventeen")
elif Number == 18:
    print("eighteen")
elif Number == 19:
    print("nineteen")


if Number < 10:
    Result = Number % 10
    number_to_text_ones(Result)
elif (Number >= 20 and Number < 100):
    First = Number // 10
    Second = (Number - (First * 10)) % 10
    Result = First * 10 + Second
    number_to_text_tens(First)
    number_to_text_ones(Second)
elif (Number >= 100 and Number < 1000):
    First = Number // 100
    Second = (Number - (First * 100)) // 10
    Third = (Number - (First * 100) - (Second * 10)) % 10
    Result = First * 100 + Second * 10 + Third
    number_to_text_hundreds(First)
    number_to_text_tens(Second)
    number_to_text_ones(Third)
```

The problem is when I input, say, 895 my output will be:

```
eight hundreds

ninety 

five
```

Few questions I have:

1. How to make my output look better?
2. Is there any way to get rid of those if statements and use something more efficient? Something like switch/case

Comment: you should use dictionaries as a replacement for switch cases in python as explained here https://stackoverflow.com/a/103081/8370670 . And if you are using python3 you should use print with end parameter to print text without a newline at the end.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the answers:

1. `print` function has an optional parameter `end` which specifies what will be written at the end of the string you are printing. Default is new line (`'\n'`). You would like to use

   ```
   print('something', end=' ')
   ```

   Nicer than that would be to first build a string with the name of entire number and the use print only once at the end.
2. A nice way to solve this is with dictionary, e.g.:

   ```
   name = {1: "one hundred",
           2: "two hundreds",
           3: "three hundreds"}[hundreds]
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect there is a library for this but I'd refactor to use the following pattern

```
ones_text = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven', 'eight', 'nine']

def number_to_text_ones(number):
    return ones_text[number - 1]
```

Comment: as sensible as this refactor is, it has literally *nothing* to do with the question asked and won't solve the problem posed by OP.

Comment: @Zinki I used both ^ this and mabac's answers and it works fine now

Answer (score 0):

You should use dictionaries as it will reduce the lines of code (if-else conditions will no more be there just a return statement would be sufficient ) and will give your code a better look also execution time will decrease because using if-else condition the program checks each every condition specified, So dictionaries will make help u alot

And for printing your output in one line this one is a better

```
print(number_to_text_hundreds(First) + number_to_text_tens(Second) + number_to_text_ones(Third))
```

number_to_text_hundereds , number_to_text_tens and number_to_text_ones returns a value corresponding to value passed to function

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you using lists of strings as follows:

```
print("Enter your number")
Number = int(input())


units    = ['', 'one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven', 'eight', 'nine']
teens    = ["ten", "eleven", "twelve", "thirteen", "fourteen", "fifteen", "sixteen", "seventeen", "eighteen", "nineteen"]
tens     = ['', '', "twenty", "thirty", "forty", "fifty", "sixty", "seventy", "eighty", "ninety"]

h = Number // 100
t = (Number % 100) // 10
u = (Number % 10)

result = []

if h == 0:
    pass
elif h == 1:
    result.append('one hundred')
else:
    result.append(units[h] + ' hundreds')

if (t == 0):
    if (u != 0):
        result.append(units[u])
    elif (h == 0):
        result = ['zero']
elif (t == 1):
    result.append(teens[u])
else:
    result.append(tens[t])
    if (u != 0):
        result.append(units[u])

result = ' '.join(result)

print(result)
# input = 895 : result = 'eight hundreds ninety five'
# input = 507 : result = 'five hundreds seven'
# input = 120 : result = 'one hundred twenty'
# input = 071 : result = 'seventy one'
# input =  16 : result = 'sixteen'
# input =   0 : result = 'zero'
```